# IEnumerable<> to IList<>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I am using Linq to query my database and returning a generic IList.

Whatever I tried I couldn't convert an IQueryable to an IList.

Here is my code.

I cannot write simpler than this and I don't understand why it is not working.

```
public  IList<IRegion> GetRegionList(string countryCode)
{
    var query = from c in Database.RegionDataSource
                where (c.CountryCode == countryCode)
                orderby c.Name
               select new {c.RegionCode, c.RegionName}; 

     return query.Cast<IRegion>().ToList(); 
}
```

This returns an list with the right number of items but they are all empty
Please help, I am bloqued with this for a couple of days now

Comment: This question and answers really illustrate the issue of duck typing, and C#/Linq limitations

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `select` statement returns an anonymous type: `new {c.RegionCode, c.RegionName}`

This can't be converted to `IRegion` - that would basically be Duck-typing, which C# doesn't support.

Your linq statement should return a type that implements `IRegion` - then your code should work.

However it shouldn't run - the `Cast<IRegion>` should throw a runtime exception.

Basically:

```
// this isn't anonymous, and should cast
public class MyRegion : IRegion {
    public string RegionCode {get;set;}
    public string RegionName {get;set;}
}

public  IList<IRegion> GetRegionList(string countryCode)
{
    var query = from c in Database.RegionDataSource
                where (c.CountryCode == countryCode)
                orderby c.Name
               select new MyRegion {RegionCode = c.RegionCode, RegionName = c.RegionName}; 

     return query.Cast<IRegion>().ToList(); 
}
```

---

**Update**

If the underlying Linq type implements `IRegion` this can be a lot simpler:

```
public  IList<IRegion> GetRegionList(string countryCode)
{
    var query = 
        from region in Database.RegionDataSource
        where region.CountryCode == countryCode
        orderby region.Name
        select region; 

     return query.ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `Cast<IRegion>()` now that you're projecting into a concrete type.

Comment: @cottsak: Yes he will - `IList<T>` is invariant.

Comment: I have my Linq autogenerated class Region that implements IRegion.
When I use it, I got another error message

Explicit construction of entity type 'xxxx.LinqToSql.xxxx.Region' in query is not allowed.

Comment: @nachid - ahh, I think we have a fix then! `Database.RegionDataSource` returns `Region`. To fix all you need is to end with `select c`

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised it's not just failing completely - you're trying to cast each result to an `IRegion`, but you're generating instances of an anonymous type, which certainly won't implement `IRegion`.

Do you *have* a concrete type which implements `IRegion`?

Answer (score 2):

The cast to `IRegion` won't work. You're selecting an anonymous type that won't implement `IRegion`. Is there a way you can create an instance of something that implements IRegion?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
public  IList<IRegion> GetRegionList(string countryCode)
{
    var query = from c in Database.RegionDataSource
                where (c.CountryCode == countryCode)
                orderby c.Name
                select new Region() 
                    {
                        RegionCode = c.RegionCode, 
                        RegionName = c.RegionName
                    }; 

     return query.ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: I need somehow to cast to IRegion before I return my query
The compiler complains that it cannot convert IList<Region> to IList<IRegion>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
public  IList<IRegion> GetRegionList(string countryCode) 
{ 
    var query = from c in Database.RegionDataSource 
                where (c.CountryCode == countryCode) 
                orderby c.Name 
                select new Region()  
                    { 
                        RegionCode = c.RegionCode,  
                        RegionName = c.RegionName 
                    };  

     return query.ToList();  
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing this 

     public IList<IRegion> GetRegionList(string countryCode) 
     { var query = from c in Database.RegionDataSource where (c.CountryCode == countryCode) orderby c.Name select c; return query.Cast<IRegion>().ToList(); } I'll return here soon and let you know Thank you for your valuable help